# Trying to get whole XML file. [#document: null] error

Tags: java, xml

I'm trying to get whole XMl(like `<HTML><BODY><item>a</item>...</HTML>`) on result. but when i execute this code, it returns `[#document: null]` on webpage.

I searched about `[#document: null]` and saw the answer that it isn't an error. But I couldn't see any result.

I want to see the result like below image.

how can I see the if it proceeded successfully or not?

I'm new to Eclipse. sorry for basic question!
[image]

```
    package web.component;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.net.URLConnection;

    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
    import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
    import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

    import org.w3c.dom.Document;
    import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

    @WebServlet({ "/XmlSelectServlet", "/xmlselect" })
    public class XmlSelectServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        //response.setContentType("");
         URL url = new URL("url");
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();    

            Document doc;
            try {
                doc = parseXML(connection.getInputStream());
                 response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
                    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
                    out.print(doc.toString());
                    out.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }   
    }
     private Document parseXML(InputStream stream) throws Exception{

            DocumentBuilderFactory objDocumentBuilderFactory = null;
            DocumentBuilder objDocumentBuilder = null;
            Document doc = null;

            try{

                objDocumentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                objDocumentBuilder = objDocumentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

                doc = objDocumentBuilder.parse(stream);

            }catch(Exception ex){
                throw ex;
            }       

            return doc;
        }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because `doc.toString()` returns a String with `[]`. The `toString()` method on a document does not convert it back to its XML format. To convert a `Document` back to its XML you will need to have some code which does that:

```
public static void printDocument(Document doc, OutputStream out) throws IOException, TransformerException {
    TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "no");
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
    transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "4");

    transformer.transform(new DOMSource(doc), 
         new StreamResult(new OutputStreamWriter(out, "UTF-8")));
}
```

Then call that to output your document:

```
try {
    doc = parseXML(connection.getInputStream());
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

    // OLD CODE
    // PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    // out.print(doc.toString());
    // out.close();

    // NEW CODE
    printDocument(doc, response.getOutputStream());
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```